# How to recreate that "image on the left, text on the right" and "text on the right image on the left" pattern?

Tags: html, css

When I often visit websites of companies I saw that common pattern where there is an image on the left side and the description the right side, as I scroll down the second column is the opposite, the image is on the right side and the text on the left side, and so on.

I tried creating something simimlar with flexbox:

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: #5c3b65;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
}

.about-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.about-container > * {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 20px 0 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
  [class*="col-"] {
    border: 1px solid orange;
  }

  .col-1 {
    flex: 25%;
  }

  .col-2 {
    flex: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="images-oddeven.css">
  <title>Odd and Even</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="about">
    <div class="about-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

However I'm sure my code doesn't work properly because I want that 25% width for images but the position of images change. So, sometimes I need that 25% column width on the left side, sometimes on the right side.

Do you think would it be easier to approach this with CSS Grid? Browser compatibility is not an issue to me. I don't need support for IE11.

Comment: This will probably be an unpopular opinion, but if you can choose between grid and flexbox, grid is nearly always a better solution.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. Microsoft will drop support for IE11 this year in November, so I think grid is production ready for now, I just didn't thought about how to approach my problem. As you can see someone answered my post and suggested that `order: 2` thing and wondering if grid has something like that.

Comment: @DBS There's not really a need to choose; they are designed to work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the same html for all rows and change the order of `col-1` in even rows.

```
.row:nth-child(2n) .col-1 {
  order: 2;
}
```

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: #5c3b65;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
}

.about-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.about-container>* {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 20px 0 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
  [class*="col-"] {
    border: 1px solid orange;
  }
  .col-1 {
    flex: 25%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    flex: 50%;
  }
  
  .row:nth-child(2n) .col-1 {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="about-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If you want to use `grid`, you can try like below

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.about-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 1fr; /* or use 50% instad of 1fr */
  margin: 0 0 50px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.row:nth-child(2n) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 25%;
}

.row:nth-child(2n) .col-2 {
  grid-area: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="about-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- / .about-container -->
</section>
<!-- / .about -->
```

Comment: Is it true that the row divs are not necessary with CSS grid?

Comment: I'll create a demo for that

Comment: Thank you. Please feel free to remove any unnecessary markup.

Comment: I can't provide a solution without using row wrapper. I think this is appropriate.

Comment: For the flexbox example this seems to work as well: `.row:nth-child(2) { flex-flow: row-reverse; }` instead of targeting the `.row:nth-child(2n) .col-1` and using `order`

Comment: yeah good point. you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I like to use display: flex; if you put two divs into one that has display flex and give them width 50% it should work.

Also, you can do orders in flex.
Here is a useful article
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I don't currently have a snippet that I can show but the article includes a few ways to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. The idea was to make the div with the image a little narrower, like 30% or so. What is the problem with the grid approach?

Comment: There is no problem with using grid, I simply prefer flexbox because it's a little simpler and more modern in relation to mobile support and overall ease of use. I could put your code into flex format if you want to see how it would look